# Set in constructor and can't be changed

Tags: java, constructor, final, protected

Hey guys I'm working on a program "Franchise". A Franchise has an owner (the owner of the franchise’s name), state (the 2-character string for the state where the franchise is located), and sales (the total sales at the franchise for a day) which are all set in a constructor and cannot be changed.

```
package prob2;

public class Franchise {
    final String name;
    final String state;
    final double sales;

protected Franchise(String name, String state, double sales ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.state = state;
    this.sales = sales;
  }
```

My question is: Being name, state, and sales have to be set in the constructor and can't be changed am I doing this right using 'protected' or is it better to set the variable to 'final'?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Please don't change the question after it's already been answered. Instead, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that modifies them at the moment, but there is nothing stopping you adding a method which does modify them. Your current path means you will have to remember that they are not supposed to change.

If your intention is for them never to change then set them to **final**. This means the compiler will check if you attempt to modify them and make sure you give them a value in the constructor. It will also make it clear to other developers (including you in a weeks time) that they are never meant to change.

Comment: I updated my code, setting the variables to final. My second question would be: being I'm setting it to final and will later pass the name to the constructor in the main method, do I still need getters and setters?

Comment: @user2745043: getters, yes, but setters make no sense in this situation, right?

Comment: You will need getters if you want to get the values out again. You can not use setters as once you give a final variable a value it is set and you can not change it.

Comment: I need to implement a compareto method that's why I was questioning the getters and setters. Wouldn't I need getters to get the values to compare?

Comment: With a compareTo you can reference the variables directly because it is in the same class. You don't need to use a getter for internal use if it is just returning the variable.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing this right using 'protected' or is it better to set the variable to 'final'?

The `protected` keyword does not mean what you think it means.  What is actually means (in this case) is:

> "This constructor can be called by any class in the same package, and any subclass of this class".

It doesn't directly "protect" the fields.

The correct solution is to add the `final` modifier to the fields you want to not change.  The Java compiler will then stop you writing (normal) Java code that modifies the respective fields.

---

We should also note that even `final` fields are not immune from being changed.  It is possible to use reflection to override the modifiers at runtime and change even a `private final` field.  If your intention is to implement hard security using `private` and `final`, you need to take account of this.  Basically, this only works as protection against untrusted code that has been sandboxed ... and even then it only protects the value of the field, not the object the field refers to.